# mysql group_concat issue

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I just trying to know is this possible the function of MYSQL `GROUP_CONCAT`  to return this type of data. Here is a scenario

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(marks) AS `i need only 40 int in this column`  FROM marks
```

when i execute this Query the result will be show like this

[image]

Result required `40`

Comment: no i need only 40 there is no average of 5 @SalmanA

Comment: Hard code `40` in your query (`SELECT 40 FROM marks LIMIT 1`), unless you have a reason we could understand.

Comment: i have a multiple value in one column and i need to extract only 40 also i mentioned my Question is this possible or not @SalmanA

Comment: [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) does not make any sense without `GROUP_BY`

Comment: What is possible or not? Your question is totally unclear. Can you give a few sample rows and the expected output? If you only need a literal `40`, a simple `SELECT 40 LIMIT 1` will do. Otherwise you need to add a few more details to your question – as it stands it is totally unclear.

Comment: @samad: The answer is `SELECT marks FROM marks WHERE marks = 40`. I cannot post it as an answer because your question and my answer does not make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select group_concat(m.marks) from 
    ( select distinct marks from marks limit 40 ) m
```

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question correctly though... :-)

Comment: @knittl: I don't know. To me, it seems that OP wants **only 40 integers**, and not **only integer 40**. But as I stated in my previous comment: don't know if understood correctly what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Advice first: normalize your database tables – a field should only contain a single value.

Now, the solution for your concrete problem: MySQL has the [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function which should do what you want:

```
SELECT marks
FROM marks
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('40', marks)
```

Comment: Thanx for sharing your experience but that not my Question

Comment: @Samad: Then what exactly is your question?!

Comment: I still don't understand. `GROUP_CONCAT` creates a single string of multiple rows, when used in combination with `GROUP BY`. »[…] want to pick one element from comma separated field« ← which element? first? middle? last? matching a certain criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(marks) AS `i need only 40 int in this column`  FROM marks
```

is working properly. You are giving `GROUP_CONCAT(marks)` the name
 `i need only 40 int in this column`, so it shows what you are saying through syntax.

> " Result required 40 "

What does it means when you use group_concat and you want to record where the marks are 40? Why not use query like

```
select * from table_name where marks='40'
```

If group_concat is a compultion, then use

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(marks) AS `i need only 40 int in this column`  FROM marks where marks='40'
```

Comment: i have already mentioned my Question is this possible or not if possible then how

Comment: your query is working properly what it have to, so whats the question arrived? means what do you whant to show in result.

Comment: i want to get 40 value in this column with the help of mysql functions

Comment: why not you using ` select * from table_name where marks='40' ` instead of group_concat,by the way why are you using group-concat, it will give you whole result not 40 only

Comment: i know this statement but that not my Question

Comment: Thanx for contribute your experience with me

Comment: @Samad if group_concat is your cumpultion then see my last line added to this answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat because we cannot continue it here because of stackoverflow rules](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9680/discussion-between-jason-vorhees-and-samad)